# Capture barcode from front camera iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, barcode, avcapturesession

In my app I've to capture a barcode with `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` and `AVCaptureSession`, when I use the rear camera all works perfectly and very fast, but when I try to read the same code from the front camera it doesn't work. I tried to mirror the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` with the following code `videoPreviewLayer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);`, it mirror the image but the device is still unable to detect barcode. There's a way to detect a barcode from the front camera?

Comment: im having the exact same issue, i need to use the front facing camera only to scan barcodes but am hardly able to get front camera to scan it. Could it be because the front facing camera flips the image it sees which would make the barcode unrecognisable or something?

Comment: I ran into this. No solution from Apple even in 2021?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There's a way to detect a barcode from the front camera?

Yes, you can use a third party library to do that. For example [ZXingObjC](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC).

You will need to setup your `ZXCapture` object like this:

```
  ZXCapture *capture = [[ZXCapture alloc] init];
  capture.camera = self.capture.front;
  capture.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusModeLocked;
```

Comment: what dose this lib do ? dose it flip the image or what ?

Comment: That lib doesn't make any difference. It does not work any better.